# ImageCorrespondingPoints[] using my own lists of unmatched points

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

`ImageCorrespondingPoints[]` finds a set of matching interest points in two images and returns their pixel coordinates. The doc says it "uses `ImageKeypoints` to find candidate corresponding points."

`ImageKeypoints` returns different numbers of candidate points for different images, so internally `ImageCorrespondingPoints[]` must be determining the correspondences between the points.

Is there a way I could supply my own sets of points to the algorithms `ImageCorrespondingPoints` uses to find correspondences?

Alternatively, is there a way I could replace the `ImageKeypoints` used by `ImageCorrespondingPoints` with my own code to extract candidate corresponding points from images?

Comment: One problem is that it is not possible extract SURF, ORB etc. descriptors for your own points. That is a major strength of `ImageKeypoints`. Any matching you can do will, consequently, not be as robust, unless you obtain descriptors somehow using functions that are not built-in. One way, anyhow, could be to implement one's own RANSAC and then use that together with `FindGeometricTransform` to find a set of corresponding points that gives a transform from one point set to the other that has a small reprojection error. (I realize this comment can be confusing; I'd make an example if I had time.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. My source images are astrophotographic (star fields), so I don't think I get much benefit from the additional features in the SURF, ORB descriptors. I'd seen a table showing some Methods provide just position based features (AGAST, FAST), but now see those methods are only available in ImageKeypoints not ImageCorrespondingPoints. Implementing my own RANSAC is exactly what I'm trying to avoid (especially given that it is already implemented somewhere behind the scenes in MM.)